# Android 4.1 Emulator not showing up the Dark holo theme

Tags: android, android-emulator

Whenever I tried to preview my application on emulator it shows with the holo.light version theme rather than the dark theme. I have tried changing the theme in the eclipse but still not working.

[image]

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>


<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />
```

Comment: where have you declared the theme show us the code

Comment: specified holo theme in the theme selection dropdown

Comment: paste your line of declaration in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The theme selection dropdown doesn't update the code, it just previews the theme in the editor.

To permanently change the theme in the application, define the theme in the
Android Manifest file, e.g..

```
    <application
        ...
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
```